# How to assign keys of dictionary with coordinates to keys of another dictionary with coordinates uniquely based on distance?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, variable-assignment

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
AllDepotsDict = {'01': [30, 48], '02': [49, 17]}
```

where keys must be strings, and the values are x and y coordinates respectively,
and

```
AllClusterCentersDict = {0: [29.67, 23.33], 1: [38.5, 87.0]}
```

where keys are centroids' ids and the values are the x and y coordinates respectively.

I want to assign each key of the first dictionary to a key of the 2nd dictionary **uniquely**, based on distance.
I want something like this:

```
AssignmentsDict = {'01':0, '02':1}
```

since the closest centroid for '01' is 0 and for '02' is 0 again but since i want **unique** assignments, i will assign to '02' the second closest centroid, which is 1.

So far i have tried the following:

```
import math
for k, v in AllDepotsDict.items():
    min_dist = 1000000

    for key, value in AllClustersCentersDict.items():

        cand_dist = math.dist(v, value)
        if cand_dist < min_dist:
            min_dist = cand_dist
            closest_centroid = key
print("Final Assignments", CentroidToDepotsAssignment)
```

The problem with this script is that it does not assign centroids to strings uniquely, since it prints the following:

```
Final Assignments {'01': 0, '02': 0}
```

while it should be like this:

```
Final Assignments {'01': 0, '02': 1}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just have to delete the centroids 0 once you have assigned point '01' to center 0. And then, search the closest center for point '02'.